# Unable to connect to pgAdmin 4 since the last update of its Docker image: Incorrect username or password

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I recently updated the [dpage/pgadmin4:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/) docker image using `docker-compose pull` on the following compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    container_name: pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@local.host
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8080
      - PGADMIN_SERVER_JSON_FILE=servers.json
    volumes:
      - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
```

But since now, each time I try to login on the landing page after having spin up my container, I face the following error message:

> "Incorrect username or password".

[image: pgadmin4 error message]

And here are the lines displayed on the server log (`docker-compose logs`) at that time:

```
pgadmin4    | ::1 - - [24/Jun/2021:21:48:21 +0000] "POST /authenticate/login HTTP/1.1" 302 209 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin4    | ::1 - - [24/Jun/2021:21:48:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 237 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin4    | ::1 - - [24/Jun/2021:21:48:21 +0000] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 1812 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
pgadmin4    | ::1 - - [24/Jun/2021:21:48:21 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico?ver=50400 HTTP/1.1" 302 265 "http://localhost:8080/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
```

What went wrong and how to fix it?
I didn't change the compose file, and it was perfectly working before the update.

More info:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

Comment: Docker compose pull will not start the containers. Have you restarted the docker docker containers again. Docker compose pull will only pull down the associated images with the compose file. Do a `docker-compose up -d` and check again

Comment: Actually, I didn't say I used `pull` to *start* the container. As stated in my first sentence, it was used to *update* the image specified in the compose file. After that, I have naturally `down -v` and `up` my container again. And since then, I have not been able to login using the credentials specified in the compose file.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug on the image 5.4

I've downgraded it to [5.3](https://hub.docker.com/layers/dpage/pgadmin4/5.3/images/sha256-5b37b0ddb5fc0251cdfab9af606f62c8b5c49b404669b44509b998bb19fd77bb?context=explore) and it works just fine.

(just lost a couple of hours to this...)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be gone with the recently published latest version (5.5 at the time of writing)

[image: latest version]

---

`docker pull dpage/pgadmin4:5.5`

https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Answer (score 0):

Same here. IT's a bug in 5.4
Upgrading to 5.5 resolves the issue:

```
FROM dpage/pgadmin4:5.5
```